# Has anyone ever reached a read or write upper-bound for an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, scalability

Are there known limitations of S3 scaling? Anyone ever had so many simultaneous reads or writes that a bucket started returning errors? I'm a bit more interested in writes than reads because S3 is likely to be optimized for reads.

Comment: Amazon S3 processes hundreds of thousands of requests per second ( http://aws.typepad.com/aws/amazon_s3/ ).  There is no limit on the number of objects per bucket, so I doubt there are any concurrency limits at the bucket level.

Comment: FYI, I've just uploaded more than 10 million files in less than 15 days, with 30 concurrent threads. Didn't encounter any limit/problem.

Comment: The project on which I am working, it is encountering this issue, Aws s3 says, 
"slow down your request rate" in error. I am working on project where read/write requests increases with increase in number of rows in CSV data. I encounter this error for 50M rows of data. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eric's comment sums it up already on a conceptual level, as addressed in the FAQ [What happens if traffic from my application suddenly spikes?](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_happens_if_traffic_from_my_application_suddenly_spikes) as well:

> Amazon S3 was designed from the ground up to handle traffic for any
>   Internet application. [...] Amazon S3’s massive scale enables us to
>   spread load evenly, so that no individual application is affected by
>   traffic spikes.

Of course, you still need to account for possible issues and *Tune [your] Application for Repeated SlowDown errors* (see [Amazon S3 Error Best Practices](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ErrorBestPractices.html)):

> **As with any distributed system**, S3 has protection mechanisms which
>   detect intentional or unintentional resource over-consumption and
>   react accordingly. **SlowDown errors can occur when a high request rate
>   triggers one of these mechanisms.** Reducing your request rate will
>   decrease or eliminate errors of this type. **Generally speaking, most
>   users will not experience these errors regularly; however,** if you
>   would like more information or are experiencing high or unexpected
>   SlowDown errors, please post to our Amazon S3 developer forum
>   http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/forum.jspa?forumID=24
>   or sign up for AWS Premium Support
>   http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/. *[emphasis mine]*

While rare, these slow downs do happen of course - here is an [AWS team response](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=89722#89816) illustrating the issue (pretty dated though):

> Amazon S3 will return this error when the request rate is high enough
>   that servicing the requests would cause degraded service for other
>   customers.  This error is very rarely triggered.  **If you do receive
>   it, you should exponentially back off**.  If this error occurs, system
>   resources will be reactively rebalanced/allocated to better support a
>   higher request rate.  As a result, the time period during which this
>   error would be thrown should be relatively short. *[emphasis mine]*

Your assumption about read vs. write optimization is confirmed there as well:

> The threshold where this error is trigged varies and will depend, in
>   part, on the request type and pattern.  In general, you'll be able to
>   achieve higher rps with gets vs. puts and with lots of gets for a
>   small number of keys vs. lots of gets for a large number of keys. 
>   When geting or puting a large number of keys you'll be able to achieve
>   higher rps if the keys are in alphanumeric order vs. random/hashed
>   order.